# How hard is Heyting satisfiability, i.e. the constructive version of SAT? In particular, is 2-HSAT NL-complete or is it harder?

Tags: computational-complexity, constructive-mathematics, sat

First of all, is it clear what I mean by $k$-HSAT?

I'm assuming that for $k>2$, $k$-HSAT is NP-complete, but the details of the reductions between $k$-HSAT and $k$-SAT aren't obvious to me.

I'm more curious about whether $2$-HSAT is as easy as $2$-SAT, since as far as I know the latter is easy because, in a Boolean algebra, $a\vee b$ is the same as $\neg a\implies b$, so that a conjunction of clauses of the form $a\vee b$ is just a bunch of implications, and the algorithms I've seen for efficiently solving $2$-SAT use the implication graph that this defines.

Comment: From Wikipedia: The problem of whether a given equation holds in every Heyting algebra was shown to be decidable by S. Kripke in 1965.[1] The precise computational complexity of the problem was established by R. Statman in 1979, who showed it was PSPACE-complete[7] and hence at least as hard as deciding equations of Boolean algebra (shown NP-complete in 1971 by S. Cook)[8] and conjectured to be considerably harder. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra

Comment: As I understand it, the question referred to in Wikipedia is still equivalent to satisfiability, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sounds like it to me, but it doesn't address the issue of 2-HSAT vs. 2-SAT.

Comment: Agreed. But I don't know enough to answer. Hopefully somebody else will still answer this good question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, we need to be clear about how we are defining **HSAT**. Over classical logic we could consider the following two definitions:

1. A formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with proposition variables amongst $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is *satisfiable* if there are $b_i \in \{\top, \bot\}$ such that $\phi(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is true. I'll refer to the corresponding decision problem as **SAT**.
2. A formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with proposition variables amongst $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is *falsifiable* (I'm not sure what the standard name for this is) if there are $b_i \in \{\top, \bot\}$ such that $\phi(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is not true. I'll refer to the corresponding decision problem as **FALSE**.

Over classical logic, this isn't such a useful distinction to make, because $\phi$ is satisfiable if and only if $\neg \phi$ is falsifiable (and vice versa). In particular, solving **FALSE** is equivalent to solving **SAT**.

By analogy with satisfiability, we could give the following definitions for a propositional formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$:

1. there is a non-trivial Heyting algebra $\mathcal{H}$ and $h_1,\ldots,h_n \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\phi(h_1,\ldots,h_n) = \top$
2. there is a [Kripke model](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KriSemForIntLog), $\langle W, \leq, \Vdash \rangle$ with root node $0 \in W$, such that $0 \Vdash \phi$
3. $\neg \phi$ is not provable in intuitionistic logic

By applying some soundness and completeness theorems, the three definitions above are equivalent. If they hold for $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, say that $\phi$ is *H-satisfiable*. I'll refer to the corresponding decision problem as **HSAT**.

By analogy with falsifiability, we could give the following definitions for a propositional formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$:

1. there is a Heyting algebra $\mathcal{H}$ and $h_1,\ldots,h_n \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\phi(h_1,\ldots,h_n) \neq \top$
2. there is a [Kripke model](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KriSemForIntLog), $\langle W, \leq, \Vdash \rangle$ with root node $0 \in W$, such that $0 \nVdash \phi$
3. $\phi$ is not provable in intuitionistic logic

By applying some soundness and completeness theorems, the three definitions above are equivalent. If they hold for $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, say that $\phi$ is *H-falsifiable*. I'll refer to the corresponding decision problem as **HFALSE**.

#### H-Satisfiability

Note that the correspondence we had before in classical logic no longer holds. In fact, for satisfiability we can say the following. By applying [Glivenko's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#Propositional_logic), we can show that $\phi$ is H-satisfiable *if and only if* it is satisfiable. In particular **HSAT** is in fact exactly the same problem as **SAT** and $k$-**HSAT** is the same as $k$-**SAT**.

#### H-Falsifiability

As Yoav Kallus pointed out in the comment, this is covered in the paper R. Statman, [Intuitionistic propositional logic is polynomial-space complete](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/23534/0000493.pdf?sequence=1) Theoretical Comput. Sci., 9:67{72, 1979. What I called **HFALSE** is **PSPACE**-complete.

This only leaves the case of $k$-**HFALSE**, which unfortunately turns out to not be that interesting. $k$-**SAT** is the decision problem for formulas in conjunctive normal form whose clauses have at most $k$ variables. Note that if $\phi$ is such a formula, then we can easily put $\neg \phi$ into *disjunctive* normal form where each conjunctive clause has at most $k$ variables, and vice versa. Hence it makes sense to define $k$-**FALSE** and $k$-**HFALSE** as the decision problems for formulas in disjunctive normal form with at most $k$ variables in each clause. In particular, this makes $k$-**FALSE** equivalent to $k$-**SAT**.

However, it turns out that for any $\phi$ in disjunctive normal form, $\phi$ is H-falsifiable (by the way, this is also true for conjunctive normal form). You can show this by constructing a Kripke model with two nodes. At the root node set every proposition variable to false and at the other node set every proposition variable to true. For any variable, $x$, neither $x$ nor $\neg x$ holds at the root node, so neither does any formula built from them with only conjunction and disjunction.

So, $k$-**HFALSE** is trivial.

Comment: The Heyting algebra in the definition of satisfiability had better be nontrivial.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, I'll correct it.